# pandas numpy.ndarray object has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas

I changed pd.ewm into pd.DataFrame.ewm just like others says (The original was pd.ewm(ups.span=RSI_N)[-1] ) . But it follows me an another problem.
What did I did wrong ? Does anybody know what is happening?

I've edited into full error message

```
from binance.client import Client
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

API_KEY = 'jHH6LNaSsdenA6xdJLRN9LVngY9KgrZ4dTzdk8685D6oquaVovY1PSuHgeQRCal5'
API_SECRET = 'DzJjJFkjppeSPQYBZg66Y2taIDr25ENfkI0G0SrxsqePYtdJX9cnxqdAHF0I8ocjS'
user = 'shinadfjinseub@gmail.com'
passwd = 'asdfaasdf!!'

client = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

# against ETH
SYMBOLS = ('ADA', 'ADX', 'BAT', 'BCC', 'DASH', 'EOS', 'IOTA',

        'LTC', 'NEO', 'OMG', 'STORJ', 'XLM', 'NANO', 'XRP', 'XVG', 'ZEC')
RSI_N = 14
RSI_THRESHOLD = 8
RUN_INTERVAL_MINS = 30

def send_email(rsi_values):
    if len(rsi_values) > 0:
        message = '\n'.join('{0:>8} {1:.2f}'.format(symbol, rsi) for (symbol, rsi) in rsi_values)
        email_text = 'From: {0}\nTo: {1}\nSubject: Stock Recommendations\n\n{2}'.format(user, user, message)

        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(user, passwd)
            server.sendmail(user, user, email_text)
            server.close()
        except:
            pass

while True:
    rsi_values = []
    for SYMBOL in SYMBOLS:
        klines = client.get_historical_klines(SYMBOL + 'ETH', Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_30MINUTE, '{} hours ago UTC'.format((RSI_N + 3) // 2))
        closings = np.asarray(klines, dtype=np.float)[-RSI_N - 1:, 4]
        diffs = np.diff(closings)
        ups = diffs.clip(min=0)
        downs = diffs.clip(max=0)
        ups_avg = pd.DataFrame.ewm(ups, span=RSI_N).mean()
        downs_avg = -pd.DataFrame.ewm(downs, span=RSI_N).mean()
        rs = ups_avg / downs_avg
        rsi = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)
        rsi_values.append((SYMBOL, rsi))

    print('\n'.join('{0:>8} {1:.2f}'.format(symbol, rsi) for (symbol, rsi) in rsi_values))
    rsi_values = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] < RSI_THRESHOLD, rsi_values))
    send_email(rsi_values)
```

error:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\심현규\PycharmProjects\FINALPROJECT\autowork.py", line 43, in <module>
    ups_avg = pd.DataFrame.ewm(ups, span=RSI_N).mean()
  File "C:\Users\심현규\PycharmProjects\FINALPROJECT\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 11282, i
n ewm
    axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_get_axis_number'
```

Comment: Please show full error message.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited it.

Comment: I hope those are not real secrets and api keys. If they are, you should immediately revoke those keys

Comment: I uploaded it cause I hope others to test it.. I edited it

Answer (score 1):

You are never actually converting `ups` to a DataFrame. The `DataFrame.ewm()` method should be applied to an instance of pandas dataframe or a pandas Series (as per Mustafa's comment).

So this should hopefully fix things:

```
while True:
    rsi_values = []
    for SYMBOL in SYMBOLS:
        klines = client.get_historical_klines(SYMBOL + 'ETH', Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_30MINUTE, '{} hours ago UTC'.format((RSI_N + 3) // 2))
        closings = np.asarray(klines, dtype=np.float)[-RSI_N - 1:, 4]
        diffs = np.diff(closings)
        ups = diffs.clip(min=0)
        ups = pd.DataFrame(ups)   # Convert to a dataframe    
        downs = diffs.clip(max=0)
        ups_avg = ups.ewm(span=RSI_N).mean()   # Now perform ewm on the dataframe
```

Hope this helps. There might be similar issues with other variables too.

Comment: ++ but `pd.DataFrame.ewm` also accepts `pd.Series`

Comment: @MustafaAydın, no, there's a separate method - `pd.Series.ewm()` for series.

Comment: Yes but `ewm` of both resolve to `NDFrame.ewm`, the parent of them.

Comment: Oh yes, I've amended the answer as per your comment.

Comment: I have another issue after changing the code.

Comment: from closings

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Comment: closings = np.asarray(klines, dtype=np.float)[-RSI_N - 1:, 4]

Comment: diffs = np.diff(closings)
        ups = diffs.clip(min=0)
        downs = diffs.clip(max=0)

        ups = pd.DataFrame(ups)
        downs = pd.DataFrame(downs)

        ups_avg = ups.ewm(span=RSI_N).mean()
        downs_avg = downs.ewm(span=RSI_N).mean()

Comment: I think I did everything right. And there was no issue with closings..

Comment: @Robinshim, what is `klines`? Is it a tuple or list? How many elements does it have?

Comment: It is a list. It's data is like.

[[1619047800000, '0.00051348', '0.00051360', '0.00050965', '0.00051065', '96255.00000000', 1619049599999, '49.1710
7734', 244, '45655.00000000', '23.32721396', '0'], [1619049600000, '0.00051058', '0.00051244', '0.00050393', '0.00
050537', '358947.00000000', 1619051399999, '182.48971859', 631, '183371.00000000', '93.30896094', '0'], .. . . . . .[1619074800000, '
0.00049179', '0.00049520', '0.00049042', '0.00049425', '126020.00000000', 1619076599999, '62.05807804', 279, '1094
72.00000000', '53.91377105', '0']]

Comment: dots are part of list that are replaced because it is too long

Comment: [[1.61906580e+12 2.44900000e-05 2.48700000e-05 2.36200000e-05
  2.37800000e-05 4.94852300e+06 1.61906760e+12 1.19573607e+02
  1.08400000e+03 2.88522700e+06 7.00542451e+01 0.00000000e+00] ....  [1.61905860e+12 2.32800000e-05 2.36800000e-05 2.30000000e-05
  2.33300000e-05 2.41177600e+06 1.61906040e+12 5.60340147e+01
  5.60000000e+02 1.12463700e+06 2.61429355e+01 0.00000000e+00]]

And this is the closing without [-RSI_N - 1:, 4]

Comment: both of them is 16 length